# Yelp API Origin http://localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: api, getjson, access-control

Using the following code, I get the error in the title of this question using Chrome's JavaScript developer console:

```
    jQuery.getJSON("http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=starbucks&location=Urbana%20IL&limit=3&ywsid=XXX",
 function(data){
  jQuery.each(data, function(i,businesses){   
   jQuery("#yelpPreview").append(businesses.url);
   if ( i == (amount - 1) ) return false;
  });
 });
```

In full, the error is: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=starbucks&location=Urbana%20IL&limit=3&ywsid=XXX. Origin http://localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I'm using MAMP as my localhost.

Is this an issue with Yelp blocking API access to a localhost, or is there an error in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using jQuery. The 'jsonp' option for datatype provided by jQuery's ajax call is a more elegant solution to this, as a short example:

```
$.ajax({
    url      : 'http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search',
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    data     : {term : 'restaurant', lat : xxx, long : xxx}, // callback is not necessary
    success  : function(data) {
        // data is a normal response shown on yelp's API page
    }
});
```